# What's wrong with this proof of Schröder-Bernstein theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

In V. A. Zorich's *Mathematical Analysis I* there is an exercise to

> Analyze the following proof of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem:
>
> $(\operatorname{card} X \leq \operatorname{card} Y) \land (\operatorname{card} Y \leq \operatorname{card} X) \Rightarrow (\operatorname{card} X=\operatorname{card} Y).$
>
> *proof.* It suffices to prove that if the sets $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are such that $X \supset Y \supset Z$ and $\operatorname{card} X=\operatorname{card} Z$, then $\operatorname{card} X=\operatorname{card} Y$. Let $f : X \rightarrow Z$ be a bijection. A bijection $g : X \rightarrow Y$ can be defined, for example, as follows:
>
> $$
> g(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \ f(x)      & \text {if $x \in f^n(X) \setminus f^n(Y)$  for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$} \\
>  x   & \text {otherwise} \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Here $f^n=f \circ \cdots \circ f$ is the $n$th iteration of the mapping $f$ and $\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.

Though it's fancy, I didn't find there is any grate mistake in this proof. But the word "analyze" strongly implies there is something wrong in this proof. Is that because I have to apply AC (axiom of choice) for finding such $x \in f^n(X) \setminus f^n(Y)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Or there's other thing going wrong here?

Comment: If $f: X\rightarrow Z$ and $X\subsetneq Y$, then there are elements of $Y$ on which $f$ isn't even defined - so what on earth is $f^n(Y)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry, there's a typo :p ... It should be $X \supset Y \supset Z$.

Comment: The proof seems to be missing an argument that the $g$ being defined is in fact a bijection. And does the $\mathbb N$ mentioned in the proof include $0$?

Comment: The argument works, it is the same that can be found for example in Jech's "Set Theory". I think "analyze" just means checking it is correct here.

Comment: @user35359 Yes, I find that example and it's much more detailed, which make me sure the proof is actually done right. Thanks you.

Comment: AC is not involved.It appears that you are asked (1) to  justify the sentence "It suffices...." and to complete the proof by showing that g is a bijection.